# Juntar vários arquivos mp3 em um único arquivo mp3

Tags: c, sistema-de-arquivos, áudio, merge

Olá! Eu gostaria de criar um programa (em linguagem C ou outra capaz) que receba como entrada um texto e me devolva como saída uma música.

Para isso eu precisaria de um arquivo texto (.txt) onde eu precisaria fazer a leitura do mesmo e vários arquivos de áudio (.mp3) cada um deles com uma nota musical. Digamos que a letra A represente a nota Dó.mp3 a letra B presente a nota Lá.mp3 a sequência das letras A e C a nota Ré.mp3.

A leitura do arquivo pra mim não seria um problema a minha dificuldade é em juntar esses arquivos .mp3 de acordo com a sequencia do texto e transformá-los em um único arquivo .mp3

Eu simplesmente não sei por onde começar. Já conversei com alguns professores mas ninguém sabe como fazer. Então eu pergunto pra vocês:

**Como eu faço para juntar vários arquivos mp3 em um único arquivo mp3?** Vocês podem me indicar algum caminho (sites, livros, cursos, etc)?

Comment: Te dei uma resposta com o caminho das pedras, não é simples de usar samples pré gravados para o que vc quer, decodificar e codificar arquivos mp3 é um porre, se seu projeto aceitar samples .wav seria um facilitador, particularmente eu partiria para outro caminho, eu acho mais interessante sintetizar todas as notas de acordo com as entradas de seu .txt, vc entraria com as notas(frequências) e a duração de cada uma, vc poderia sintetizar as entradas usando seno ou cosseno ...

Comment: Realmente a sua pergunta está ampla. Você já tem uma resposta excelente do colega @ederwander (embora não seja numa das linguagens que você solicitou), mas eu ainda sugiro que você edite a sua pergunta para deixar ela mais focada. Pode começar definindo a linguagem (C e C++ são distintas - afinal vc quer em C ou em C++?), e pode também deixar pra lá toda essa questão de ler as notas do arquivo. O seu problema parece ser mesmo como juntar dois arquivos de áudio em formato mp3.

Comment: Ainda assim, se você deseja "compor" músicas usando notas musicais, há outras formas possíveis. Você não precisa ler um arquivo de áudio comprimido com cada uma das notas e juntá-los, você pode simplesmente *emitir* tais notas. Dependendo da biblioteca ou SO que você usa, existem funções como o [Beep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx) que te permite definir a frequência e a duração [de uma nota](http://www.amattos.eng.br/Public/INSTRUMENTOS_MUSICAIS/Textos/Div/notas.htm). Ou, tendo os mp3/wave, basta você tocá-los na sequencia, sem juntar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível de se fazer em qualquer linguagem, mas não é tão simples :-(, você vai precisar decodificar o áudio e armazenar de forma pura dentro de um vetor ou matriz, o processo lógico é:

1. Decodificar o primeiro arquivo .mp3
2. armazenar o áudio decodificado em um Vetor de N posições
3. Decodificar o próximo arquivo .mp3
4. Concatenar o novo vetor decodificado no final do outro vetor
5. fazer isso e um loop até terminar de ler todos os arquivos do seu .txt
6. Codificar o vetor para .mp3

Decodificar .mp3 é bem complexo, se insistir em usar C eu recomendo que você link seu projeto com uma lib específica capaz de fazer decode, já usei bastante o [libmad](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mad/files/libmad/) pra fazer coisas parecidas em C, talvez seja mais fácil você fazer o mesmo processo usando .wav pois para decodificar e codificar é mais simples ...

Em Python2.7 pode ser relativamente simples decodificar .mp3 usando o [Pymedia](http://pymedia.org/)

```
import pymedia.audio.acodec as acodec
import pymedia.muxer as muxer

name='Sia - Chandelier.mp3';


name1= str.split(name,'.')


if name1[ -1 ].lower()  == 'mp3':


    dm= muxer.Demuxer( name1[ -1 ].lower() )
    f=open(name, 'rb' )
    dec= None
    s= " "
    sinal=[]
    while len( s ):
        s= f.read( 4096 )
        if len( s ):
            frames= dm.parse( s )
            for fr in frames:
                if dec== None:
                    dec= acodec.Decoder( dm.streams[ 0 ] )
                r= dec.decode( fr[ 1 ] )
                if r and r.data:
                    din = np.fromstring(r.data, dtype=np.int16)
                    sinal.append(din)
```

O vetor/lista `sinal` vai conter o áudio `Sia - Chandelier.mp3` totalmente decodificado, tudo que você precisa fazer agora é ir concatenando cada arquivo lido no final do vetor `sinal`, por fim vc deve codificar o vetor sinal para arquivo .mp3, vc precisa de algo parecido com isso para efetuar o encode:

```
# Open muxer and encoder

          if enc== None:
            params= { 'id': acodec.getCodecID(type),
                      'bitrate': bitrate,
                      'sample_rate': r.sample_rate,
                      'channels': r.channels }
            print 'Encoder params:', params
            mx= muxer.Muxer( type )
            stId= mx.addStream( muxer.CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO, params )
            enc= acodec.Encoder( params )
            fw= open(fOutput, 'wb')
            ss= mx.start()
            fw.write(ss)

          enc_frames= enc.encode( pack("%dh"%len(sinal), *(sinal)) )
          if enc_frames:
            for efr in enc_frames:
              ss= mx.write( stId, efr )
              if ss:
                fw.write(ss)
```

Se fosse totalmente em .wav isso poderia ser feito em poucas linhas usando python, espero que isso te dê um norte!

Comment: Excelente! Vai me ajudar muito!